# Type hinting an extended abstract class

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have an abstract class `AbstractCharacter`, and concrete classes: `soldier` and `knight`, and many other characters.

How do I create the interface to say that the prop `character` will be a class that extends `AbstractCharacter`

e.g.

```
export abstract class AbstractCharacter {
    public abstract name: string;
    public abstract hp: number;
}

export class Soldier extends AbstractCharacter {
    public name = "Soldier";
    public hp = 100;
}

class Knight extends AbstractCharacter {
    public name = "Knight";
    public hp = 100;
}
```

And usage:

```
interface IFormationCharacter {
  character: T extends AbstractCharacter // this doesn't work because T doesn't exist
  character: typeof AbstractCharacter // this doesn't allow for extending, i.e. new character() will say "Cannot create an instance of abstract class"
}

export default class FormationCharacter extends React.Component<IFormationCharacter> {
  constructor(props: IFormationCharacter) {
    super(props);
```

I know I can do `typeof Knight | typeof Soldier | typeof ...`, but surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I create the interface to say that the prop character will be a class that extends AbstractCharacter

You can use a generic interface for that:

```
interface IFormationCharacter<T extends AbstractCharacter> {
  character: T;
}
```

You will then have to use the interface with a type parameter like this:

```
IFormationCharacter<Knight>
IFormationCharacter<Soldier>
// or keep it generic
export default class FormationCharacter<T> extends React.Component<IFormationCharacter<T>> {
  constructor(props: IFormationCharacter<T>) {
    super(props);
```

Depending on your needs though, the best might be to stick with an abstract property `character: AbstractCharacter`.

Comment: Guessing  there's no way to keep it general, without needing to specify the concrete class?

Comment: Exactly, you will have to carry the type on the classes using this interface so you will probably have to stick with character: AbstractCharacter